# Getting the latest git commit id from URL on internal git using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, git-commit

With the following function I am extracting the latest git commit id in a short form and write it into a text file.

```py
from os.path import exists
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def get_git_commit_id(txt_file: str) -> str:
    """
    Gets the latest git commit id and places in the txt file if not exists
    Parameters:
    ==========
    :param txt_file: name of the txt file
    Returns:
    ==========
    :return: the latest git commit id
    """
    if not exists(txt_file):
        print(f"'{txt_file}' did not exist before")  # for logging
    try:
        process = Popen("git rev-parse --short HEAD", stdout=PIPE)
        output = process.communicate()[0]
    except Exception as error:
        output = bytes("latest", "utf-8")
        print("It could not read the .git", error)  # for logging
    with open(txt_file, "w", encoding="utf8") as file:
        file.write(output.decode("utf-8"))
    file = open(txt_file, "r", encoding="utf8")
    git_commit_id = file.readline().strip()
    return git_commit_id

get_git_commit_id("git_commit_id.txt")
```

However this code only works when I have my `.git` dir inside my project.

How can extract the latest git commit id in a short form from the URL where my project placed on the internal git?

---

**References:**

- [What does git rev-parse do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798862/what-does-git-rev-parse-do)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Github latest commit url using cli with respect to current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69099079/how-to-get-github-latest-commit-url-using-cli-with-respect-to-current-branch)

Comment: @Tzane, thank you for your idea, I will try it, however, it is for powershell ... maybe this article can support me https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/executing-powershell-from-python/

Comment: Consider, e.g., the Git repository for Git (well, an official clone thereof) [here](https://github.com/git/git/branches). Which of the four or so hash IDs for branches `main`, `maint`, `next`, and `seen` is "the latest"? (Why?)

Comment: @torek, by *"the latest"* I mean the latest commit done in the master branch. Back to your question why? because it is the main branch in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following code I was able to get the desired output:

```py
# imports
from os import devnull
from os.path import exists
from logging import getLogger
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl
from urllib.request import urlopen
from ssl import create_default_context
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
from subprocess import call, Popen, STDOUT, PIPE

logger = getLogger(__name__)

project_git_url = "https://path/to/your/git.com/?p=your-project;a=summary"
cert = None

def get_git_commit_id(txt_file: str) -> str:
    """
    Gets the latest git commit id and places in the txt file if not exists
    Parameters:
    ==========
    :param txt_file: name of the txt file
    Returns:
    ==========
    :return: the latest git commit id
    """
    if not exists(txt_file):
        logger.info(
            msg=f"The following text file does not exist : '{txt_file}'. Now it was created.",
            exc_info=False,
        )

    output = bytes("latest", "utf-8")

    git_check = call(["git", "master"], stderr=STDOUT, stdout=open(devnull, 'w'))

    if git_check != 0:
        process = Popen("git rev-parse --short HEAD", stdout=PIPE)
        output = process.communicate()[0]
    else:
        logger.debug(
            msg=f"It could not read the .git repository to extract the latest git commit id.",
            exc_info=False,
        )
        try:
            url = urlopen(project_git_url, context=create_default_context(cafile=cert))
            url_as_xml = url.read().decode("utf-8")

            docs = parseString(url_as_xml)
            html = docs.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]
            body = html.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]

            for div_element in body.getElementsByTagName("div"):
                if 'page_nav' in div_element.attributes.items()[0]:
                    for href in div_element.getElementsByTagName("a"):
                        href_content = href.attributes.items()[0][1]
                        if 'a=commit;' in href_content:
                            parsed_href_content = parse_qsl(href_content, encoding='utf-8', separator=';')
                            output = bytes(parsed_href_content[2][1][:6], "utf-8")
        except Exception as error:
            logger.debug(
                msg=f"It could not get the latest git commit id from the git : {project_git_url}.\nThe following error occurred : {error}",
                exc_info=False,
            )
    with open(txt_file, "w", encoding="utf8") as file:
        file.write(output.decode("utf-8"))
    file = open(txt_file, "r", encoding="utf8")
    git_commit_id = file.readline().strip()
    return git_commit_id
```

It also includes the parsing of the URL where the internal git located.

---

**References:**

- [Multiple try codes in one block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322208/multiple-try-codes-in-one-block)
- [Python script to determine if a directory is a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687394/python-script-to-determine-if-a-directory-is-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly installing gitpython via pip as follow `pip install gitpython`

after;

```py
import git

repo_url = 'https://your-repository-url.com/your-repo.git'

# clone the repository
repo = git.Repo.clone_from(repo_url, '/path/to/local/repo', depth=1)

# get the latest commit
latest_commit = repo.head.commit

# print the commit id
print(latest_commit.hexsha)
```